# OpenAPI I want to query monthly usage

Tags: openai-api

OpenAPI I want to query monthly usage, including Total usage so far this month and hard limit. I can only provide account number, password and key. These three data will be saved in txt file. Need to write code in python。
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IF7TS.png)

Need to write code in python, thank you

Comment: Please give me a complete case, not a call to a certain method, thank you.

Comment: I learned that Total usage can be obtained through sess so far this month and hard limit. Now I only need to provide the code to obtain sess using the account number and password.